# Swift 3 no such module within Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode

Consider me an absolute newbie for Swift 3. Everything I read seems to contradict each other. I am trying to  test the [MongoKitten module.](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten)

I managed to create a simple Xcode 8.1 project with my Package.swift containing:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MongoKittenTest",
    dependencies: [
       .Package(url: "https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten.git", majorVersion: 2, minor: 0)
    ]
)
```

As instructed in the link above, I create a swift source file with a simple line of:

```
import MongoKitten
```

When I build (from within Xcode), i get a 'no such module  MongoKitten'. I know this is trivial but I can build everything within when I run `swift build` in a terminal with no issue. How is it not possible to build within Xcode? How do I fix this issues to build within Xcode. 
Thanks

Comment: Add MongoKitten to the right target on Xcode.

Comment: I do not know what Package is. But I cannot help noticing that your package is named `MongoKittenTest`, not `MongoKitten`. Could that be important?

Comment: Thanks but that is name of the project within Xcode/Swift. It builds so it seems ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you've managed to find your answer by now but I'll post my two cents here. Your Package.swift is correct, but you'll need to generate an Xcode project from SPM using `swift package generate-xcodeproj` on the command line. After that you can open your `MongoKittenTest.xcodeproj` file using Xcode which would allow you to start.

MongoKitten 3 will be released within the next few days, so you'd need to change the `majorVersion` to 3 if you were to use the new features and documentation.